# Adding a list item in C# takes 5 minutes after calling the initial Update()

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, timer-jobs, performance, add-item

I have a timer job that queries an external list, and then copies items into a regular SharePoint list.  I store the ID of the external list item on the SP list item so I can update instead of add if appropriate.

In order to fully add an new item programmatically, you have to call `list.Items.Add()` to get a new `SPListItem` object, set field values on it, then call `item.Update()`. The only field I set during the initial add is the field that stores the ID of the external item.  There are no required fields.  There are no workflows on the SP list.  I'm testing this on my Dev environment, and the SP list that is getting new items added is initially empty.

However, after calling `item.Update()`, it takes nearly exactly 5 minutes 30 seconds before code execution continues.  I am logging, and I set up very explicit logging which is how I see this.  Here's the method that does the adding (I turned the logging code into comments, but that's where the log entries are being made):

```
private SPListItem AddNewItem(SPListItem externalCTItem, SPList list)
{
    // Log: entering method

    SPListItem newItem = null;
    string externalItemID = externalCTItem["ID"].ToString();
    try
    {
        // Log: Calling list.items.add()
        newItem = list.Items.Add();

        // Log: Setting field on new item
        newItem["ExternalDB_ID"] = int.Parse(externalItemID);

        // Log: Calling newItem.Update()
        newItem.Update();

        // Log: New item created  <-- this gets logged around 5m 30s after the last log entry
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log: exception & stacktrace
    }

    // Log: exiting method
    return newItem;
}
```

I then go into another method where I set a bunch of other fields, and call `item.Update()` again after that, and that all works fine, the big delay is only after the initial update that commits the newly added item.

**Why would it take five minutes to add a new item to a list?**

Oh, also want to add that if I go to the SP list, I can see the newly added item with the one field set.  Which means the initial update actually worked, and quickly, it's just whatever happens at the end of `item.Update()` is taking forever.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
newItem = list.Items.Add();
```

with

```
newItem = list.AddItem();
```

SPList.AddItem() method is much more faster especially while dealing with a List with large number of items.

Refer to: [SPList.Items.Add() v/s SPList.AddItem()](https://piyushksingh.com/2015/03/15/splist-items-add-vs-splist-additem/)

Comment: In a nutshell, it is because `list.Items.Add()` does retrieve *all* list items before it adds a new item.

Comment: @Salah yes, but that was my point in saying that I'm testing that on my Dev environment and the list that is getting things added to it initially is **empty**.  The fact that `list.Items.Add()` retrieves all items should be irrelevant because initially there are zero items, and the first add still has the five minute problem.

Comment: @LZ_MSFT I have read that `AddItem` is faster than `Add`, but my logging entries show that the time between when I log that I'm about to call `Add` and the next log entry that I'm about to set the field value is milliseconds.  So it seems that the time it takes to call `Add` is negligible.  The delay is after I call `Update`, not after I call `Add`.  Please re-read my question.

Comment: Also keep in mind my final comment - by going to the list in a browser, I can see that `Update` has been applied, I can see the new item in the list with the one field set to the correct value.  However, even though the `Update` worked, code execution does not continue to the final logging line where I log that the item created successfully for 5m 30s.  So the delay is not even necessarily with the `Update` itself, it is _after_ the update, with whatever cleanup code finishes the `Update` method before returning execution to the caller.